# How do I get weapon mods?

Tags: xcom-2

I know that there is a random chance to get some loot from enemies when you kill them. However, many of my soldiers don't have modded weapons due to not having found enough.

Other than looting, is there any other way to get weapon mods?  Can you build them?

It seems logical to me that XCOM should be able to build a scope for a gun but I've not seen anywhere to do so.

Comment: I suspect the downvoter won't be back to read this comment but I'm curious as to why...

Comment: Worth mentioning the Vulture perk in the Guerrilla training school will yield more weapons mods.

Comment: If you find yourself hurting for weapon-mods, [this game mod](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=620445360) increases the amount you find from loot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Weapon mods can not be built. But:

- The black market will often offer you weapon mods in exchange for intel.
- The "Vulture" perk in the Guerilla Tactics School will increase the number of mods you find.

Another thing you can do which doesn't give you more weapon mods *per se* but increases their availability is getting the continent bonus which allows you to remove mods from weapons and put them on different ones.

Also keep in mind that when a soldier with a modded weapon is injured, you can temporarily equip them with an unmodded weapon to make the modded weapon available for another soldier. So you don't need enough mods to mod the gun of *every* soldier, only enough for a full squad.

Comment: There is a continent bonus that allows removal of mods, however it is not "Australia's". The continent bonus is randomly assigned per game; my current Australia bonus is instant armour projects.

Comment: @Odalrick Ah, good to know. I thought the continent bonuses were static like in XCOM1.

Comment: I was just thinking I'd recently grabbed oceania and not seen this! :) Thanks for the tips. Will have to go pick up vulture at my earliest opportunity.

Comment: There are also something like 14 continent bonuses, and only 6 continents in-game, so some bonuses just flat out won't happen.